# Splunk query to get non matching ID from two query

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

```
Index=* sourcetype="publisher" namespace="app_1" | table ID message | where message="published"


Index=* sourcetype="consumer" namespace="app_1" | table ID message | where message="consumed"
```

I want to display non matching ID by comparing both the query, how can I achieve this.

If query 1 is giving 100 records and query 2 is giving 90 records and all 90 records are present in query 1 them I want to see 10 records which are not present in query 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve this outcome.

The following counts the number of consumer and producers events for each ID, then shows the IDs of the events that occur only once.

```
index=* sourcetype="publisher" OR sourcetype="consumer" namespace="app_1" ID="*" | stats count by ID | where count<2
```

In this next method, we use a sub search and a join. This has the benefit of giving you the full event, not just the ID.

```
index=* sourcetype="publisher" namespace="app_1" ID="*" | join type=outer ID [ search index=* sourcetype="consumer" namespace="app_1" ID="*" | eval does_match=1 ] | where isnull(does_match)
```

Comment: Thanks for your input.. I tried your suggested input but it's giving some extra record having different message.. I want to consider the message criteria which I have mentioned. Please suggest. Thanks

Comment: index=* sourcetype="publisher" namespace="app_1" ID="*" message="published" | join type=outer ID [ search index=* sourcetype="consumer" namespace="app_1" ID="*" message="consumed" | eval does_match=1 ] | where isnull(does_match)